# Need to check whether a project is checkedout or not

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-project

How to check whether we can check out a project or not.
projects are stored in sharepoint.
Always this code is printing unable to checkout

```
Sub macro()

Dim a As Project

Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Winproj.exe /s https://inside.com/PWA/QWER/Project.aspx", vbNormalFocus

Sleep 3000

FileOpenEx Name:="<>\" & "ProjectNAME", ReadOnly:=True, DoNotLoadFromEnterprise:=False

Set a = Projects.Item(1)

a.Activate

If (Projects.CanCheckOut(ActiveProject.Name)) Then

    Debug.Print "Can check out the project"
Else

    Debug.Print "Cannot checkout the project"

End If

End Sub
```

It will be very helpful

Comment: If i pass only the filename. it always print "Cannot checkout the project"
and if i pass the serverpath+filename that is "https://inside.com/PWA/QWER/VI_Test_file" it always prints "Can check out the project"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the code inside MS-Project VBA, use the Code below:

```
Sub CheckOutProject(docCheckOut As String)

' Determine whether project can be checked out
If Projects.CanCheckOut(docCheckOut) = True Then
    Debug.Print "Can check out the project"

    ' if you want, you can check it out
    Projects.CheckOut docCheckOut
Else
    Debug.Print "Cannot checkout the project"
End If

End Sub
```

Use the `Test` code below to test it out:

```
Sub Test()

Dim FullPath As String

' Full Path equals the full SharePoint Path & File name (including extension)
FullPath = "http://share.Comapny.com/sites/Test123/Project%20Documentsnew/Project%20Files/Project_1.mpp"
CheckOutProject FullPath ' call the Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai.. but it is not working.. I have checked giving the full sharepoint path and filename including extension but cancheckout is not working.

Do you any idea why this ain't working

Comment: in this case cancheckout is always false..
but if i pass serverpath and file name excluding extension then cancheckout is always true.
Got stuck with this from last 10 days. any help is welcome